# create list of objects without using list method or library. c#

Tags: c#, list, class, oop

**My situation**

- create a list of objects using just classes

**This how code work**

- with the class `ListRatings` i can create a list of `Rating` (without using list method that c# offer with the library System.Collections.Generic)

(you can see what attribute and method have class `ListRatings` and class `Rating` in code bellow)

**Issue**

when i try to print all rating i added to my list, my program print just first and last!

**My code**

class ListRating:

```
public class ListRatings
{
    private Rating first;
    private Rating last;

    public ListRatings()
    {
        first = null;
        last = null;
    }
    public void InsertNewRat(Rating rating)
    {
        if (first == null)
        {
            first = rating;
            last = rating;
        }
        else
        {
            first.setNext(rating);
            last.setNext(rating);
        }
    }
    public void PrintRats()
    {
        Rating e = first;

        Console.WriteLine(e.getMatter());
        Console.WriteLine(e.getDate());
        Console.WriteLine(e.getRate());

        e = e.getNext();

        Console.WriteLine(e.getMatter());
        Console.WriteLine(e.getDate());
        Console.WriteLine(e.getRate());

        e = e.getNext();

        Console.WriteLine(e.getMatter());
        Console.WriteLine(e.getDate());
        Console.WriteLine(e.getRate());

    }
}
```

class Rating:

```
public class Rating
{
    private int rate;
    private string matter;
    private DateTime date;
    private Rating next;

    public Rating(int rate, string matter, DateTime date)
    {
        this.rate = rate;
        this.matter = matter;
        this.date = date;
        next = null;
    }

    public int getRate()
    {
        return rate;
    }

    public string getMatter()
    {
        return matter;
    }

    public DateTime getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }

    public Rating getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Rating valutazione)
    {
        next = valutazione;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ListRatings lr = new ListRatings();
        Rating r1 = new Rating(9, "Math", new DateTime(2021, 10, 5));
        Rating r2 = new Rating(10, "sport", new DateTime(2021, 11, 3));
        Rating r3 = new Rating(6, "English", new DateTime(2021, 11, 7));

        lr.InsertNewRat(r1);
        lr.InsertNewRat(r2);
        lr.InsertNewRat(r3);

        lr.PrintRats();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Math
05/10/2021 00:00:00
9
English
07/11/2021 00:00:00
6
```

and the program stop and say error: System.NullReferenceException [is in the second `e.getNext();` i used in the class `ListRating`]

with this output you can see that is printing the first one and jump to the last one without printing the second one.

**The output i need is**

```
Math
05/10/2021 00:00:00
9
Sport
10
03/11/07 00:00:00
English
07/11/2021 00:00:00
6
```

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Have you checked this implementation for a linked list? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-implementation-in-c-sharp/

Comment: what's the benefits of a linked list over a standard list ?

Comment: our teacher give us to do it, i mean it's not bad at all. we often do something in hard way when we can just do it in an easy way, but is like training. and also for that: Linked lists are an ordered collection of objects. So what makes them different from normal lists? Linked lists differ from lists in the way that they store elements in memory. While lists use a contiguous memory block to store references to their data, linked lists store references as part of their own elements.

Comment: An advantage would be, it's faster to insert or remove elements from the middle of a modestly large linked list since you update pointers instead of copying a potentially large block of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't correctly updating your linked list. This code:

```
else
{
    first.setNext(rating);
    last.setNext(rating);
}
```

always sets both the first and last node's next node to the one you're trying to insert.

Instead, you want

```
else
{
    last.setNext(rating);
    last = rating;
}
```

This sets the node that's currently last to the new node, then updates your pointer to the last node to rating, which should now be last in the linked list.

As for the NullReferenceException, @TheVillageIdiot is correct

Comment: I ran it and get the output you expect...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a linked list implementation. Not sure if you need `last` in your `RatingsList` class. Personally, I would rename `first` to `rating` as well. The issue is how you are iterating over the ratings in `PrintRats` function. Change it to this and then try:

```
public void PrintRats()
{
    Rating e = first;
    
    while(e!=null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.getMatter());
        Console.WriteLine(e.getDate());
        Console.WriteLine(e.getRate());

        e = e.getNext();
    }
}
```

Also, you can move all those `Console.WriteLine` in the above method into `Rating` class. Lastly, naming methods `PrintRats` instead of `PrintRatings` does not make it concise.

PS: If I'm sounding cranky, this is still before morning tea.

Comment: i use many console writeline instead of cycle to help with design my bad english. so the first 3 lines were for first 3 line on output etc...

Comment: with your code i didn't get the error but the program still print just the first and last one

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust this solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<int>();
        list.Append(1);
        list.Append(2);
        list.Append(3);
        list.Append(4);
        list.Append(5);

        list.Print();

        var list2 = new List<int>(11, 22, 33);
        list.Concat(list2);
        list.Print();
    }
}

public class List<T>
{
    Node<T> first;
    Node<T> last;

    public List()
    {

    }

    public List(params T[] data)
    {
        Append(data);
    }

    public void Append(params T [] data)
    {
        foreach (T d in data)
        {
            var n = new Node<T> { data = d };
            if (last == null)
            {
                first = n;
                last = n;
            }
            else
            {
                last.next = n;
                last = n;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Concat(List<T> list)
    {
        if (last == null)
        {
            first = list.first;
            last = list.last;
        }
        else
        {
            last.next = list.first;
            last = list.last;
        }
    }

    public void Print() 
    {
        var n = first;
        while (n != null)
        {
            Debug.Write(n.data);
            if (n.next != null)
                Debug.Write(" -> ");

            n = n.next;
        }
        
        Debug.WriteLine("");
    }
}

public class Node<T>
{
    public T data { get; set; }
    public Node<T> next { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the solution i need is without using list method. (is possibile)

Comment: Just change "List<T>" to "MyList<T>", and "List" to "MyList"...

Comment: i didn't get it. i dont mean name but the list method. in others word my code don't have to contains something like that: list<T>...

Comment: My List class is my own class, not the .NET List class. You can rename it whatever you like, that's the point. Delete the next() from your Rating class, than create your list like so : var ratings = new MyList<Rating>(). Etc...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).